# How do I segue from programmatically created UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, segue

I have programmatically created `UIImage` instances which increases as the number of imageArray count increases and `UIImage` are set to them programmatically. Since those `UIImageView` are not visible in Storyboard, how can I segue from that `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController` containing an instance of `UIImage` to show image in detail. How to segue to another `UIViewController` when any of my `UIImageView` is touched.

Here is the code:

```
#import "FirstPageViewController.h"

@interface FirstPageViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property UIImage *image;
@property  NSArray *imgArray;;
@property NSMutableArray *imgNameArray;
@property UIView *containerView;
@property UIView *containerView2;

@end



@implementation FirstPageViewController

for (NSString *img in imgArray) {

    [imgNameArray addObject:img];
}

int Y = 0;
int X = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<imgNameArray.count; i++) {

        NSString *imgName = imgNameArray[i];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(X, Y, 145, 109);
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:2];
        [imageView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor ]];
        if ((i%2)==0) {
            X = 154;
        }else {
            X = 0;
        }

        if ((i%2) ==0) {
            Y = i *  59;
        }
        [containerView addSubview:imageView];           
    }

[self.scrollView addSubview: containerView];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, imgNameArray.count * 67);
```

Comment: you can use button for this, so easily manage click  event of images

Comment: use UICollectionView it's easier to create the layout using the tools already provided than to create it manually.

Comment: It's always better to post actual code than a bunch of code-like stuff that won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how you've set up your view controller, the controller can always segue to another view controller using `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. So if you've set up your storyboard so that there's a segue with the identifier `myDetailSegue` leading from the image array view controller to the image detail view controller, the image array controller can do this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myDetailSegue" sender:self];
```

So, one way to handle your task is to create an action in your image array controller:

```
-(IBAction)goToDetailController:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    // get the image view from the gesture recognizer
    UIImageView *tappedView = (UIImageView*)sender.view;
    // save the image from the image view
    self.detailImage = tappedView.image;
    // start the detail segue
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myDetailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Now you just need to attach a gesture recognizer to each image view, setting it's target to the image array view controller and action to your new `goToDetailController` action. You'll also need a `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method just like you always do when using segues. That method can set the detail view controller's image to `self.detailImage`, since you wisely saved that in the action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UICollectionView` for show, the images. Each cell have a identifier (like `indexPath` from `UITableview`) so, for each cell that will touched you will take this value and reserve this like a ID for your images. Search the image connected for this ID and load in `DetailViewController`.

`UICollectionView` has a method that detects which cell has been touched.

You can share the `imgNameArray` variable using a Singleton. And using the same "ID" and send to `DetailViewController`, you can load the same image referenced.

This is one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add UITapGestureRecognizer to each of your UIImageview and define unique tag for each Imageview (as per your forloop).

In you gesture recognizer method, you can get tag by

```
[(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender view].tag
```

Use this tag to get perticular image from your array.
And performSegue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIButton like this below.

Set its BG image and put tag each button.

Then in its selector, check tag to determine which image to be passed.

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:BUTTON_RECT];
[btn setBackgroundImage:YOUR_IMAGES forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePushEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setTag:i]; // you can set your defined tag here plus int i in your loop
.
.
.
[self.scrollView addSubview:btn];



- (void) handlePushEvent:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    // PERFORM SEGUE HERE or YOU CAN ALSO PUSH THE VC    

    int btnTag = sender.tag;
    for(int ctr=0; ctr<imgNameArray.count; ctr++)
    {
        if(ctr == btnTag) {

            NextViewController *nextVC = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            nextVC.passedImage = imgNameArray[ctr];    // create a property in your next VC, then assign like this here
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```